# Download Packages and Dependencies on Windows 8.1, then move and install them on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, windows, offline

I recently installed Ubuntu on an ancient PC. Its fantastic, but I don't have any sort of internet connection at home. I was wondering if It would be possible to download a package and its dependencies on my School computer (Windows 8.1), move them to a USB drive, and install them on my offline Ubuntu PC. I've heard of Synaptic, but I don't know how to install it on my offline PC and don't know if it supports Windows. Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Download your package on windows. Then mount that drive that saved the file.

Then use `sudo dpkg -i your-package`